# Cannot create a new project with Ionic 4:Downloading integration cordova - failed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ubuntu-18.04

I want to create a new Ionic project but I'm unable to do it. Its giving an error:

[image: please cheack this image]

I have Ionic 4.
Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with 'sudo'?

Comment: or changing the permissions of the folder that contains that file?

Comment: I tried with sudo and it worked but didn't created the www directory.

Comment: Is giving another error: Failed to load index.html

Comment: Can you please update your answer what is the error message you got with `sudo` command?

Comment: Failed to load index.html

Comment: try to uninstall ionic and install latest version...

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading ionic to 3.20.0 using

```
  npm install -g cordova ionic@3.20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission issue.

Create project :

```
sudo ionic start physics blank
```

Then enter login password.